# how to change image when we select dropdown value?

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.3.3

I have created a custom dropdown attribute name "manufactures_guarantee_length",
and its value like 1_year_guaranty,2_year_guaranty,3_year_guaranty, more,
in the product details page, I call that attribute,
now when we change the attribute value in any product that kind of image should change at the front-end product detail page,

for that, I have created a layout file catalog_product_view.xml and guaranty.phtml file,
in phtml file, I code like

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo $product->getData('manufactures_guarantee_length'); ?>
```

so I get the value of dropdown, so now how to change like Image as per dropdown?
please suggest me on this.
Thanks in advance.
.

Comment: you want to change images based on product attribute `manufactures_guarantee_length`?

Comment: @RizwanKhan yes, if we select attribute then the image change like I select guaranty_1 attribute value, then guaranty_1.jpg display

Comment: this is product attribute you are talking about not a custom option, right?

Comment: @RizwanKhan i have created a custom dropdown attribute and its work on product level,

Comment: @RizwanKhan Yes, this is product attribute,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing the image on the product view page of the gallery You first need to override `gallary.phtml` file in your theme or your custom module.

```
view/frontend/templates/product/gallary.phtml
```

Add the below script in `gallary.phtml` to change the JSON data of the gallery and load the images accordingly. You need to add your custom conditions for the images.

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/gallery/gallery'
], function ($, gallery) {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var allimgsobj = '<?php echo $block->getGalleryImagesJson(); ?>';
        var manufacturer = "<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getData('manufactures_guarantee_length'); ?>";

        $('.gallery-placeholder').on('gallery:loaded', function () {

            var res = [{}];
            $.each(JSON.parse(allimgsobj), function(i, obj) {
                if(obj.caption != null && obj.caption.toLowerCase() == manufacturer.toLowerCase()){
                    res[i] = obj;
                }
            });

            var gallery = $('.gallery-placeholder').data('gallery');
            gallery.fotorama.load(res); // this will reload the gallary with fresh json data
            gallery.first(); // this will select first image on load in gallary
        });
    });
});
```

my condition is based on caption of images, you can change it to name of the images.